# Accessing Ansible Dictionary

Tags: python, ansible

Apologies if the question is really simple, still learning and was not able to locate the exact answer of what I was after for.

I have the following Dictionary:

```
guests:
  small:
     name: small-{{ rand_gb_var }}
     mem: 1024
     cpus: 1
     os_type: rhel7
     file_type: qcow2
  large:
     name: large-{{ rand_gb_var }}
     mem: 2048
     cpus: 2
     os_type: rhel7
     file_type: qcow2
  XL:
     name: small-{{ rand_gb_var }}
     mem: 4096
     cpus: 4
     os_type: rhel7
     file_type: qcow2
```

and I am trying to ONLY access the small key and it's values one task at a time and don't want to go through the whole dictionary every time my task runs.

The task that I am running is:

```
- name: create disk
  command: >
           virt-builder --format qcow2 centos-7.4
           -o {{ vm_location }}/{{ guests.small.name }}.{{ 
           guests.small.file_type }}
           --root-password password:{{ root_pass }}
  when: guests.small.name  not in disks.stdout
  with_items: '{{ guests.keys() }}'
```

However, this appears to be looping through all of the keys and only the 'small' one.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove *with_items: '{{ guests.keys() }}'* . There is no *item* used.